# Owin with custom ORM framework (not Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ormlite-servicestack

I was recently using Entity framework together with Identity and OWIN but no I no longer want to use Entity and instead use OrmLite from ServiceStack.

The problem I'm facing right now is I don't quite understand how to replace this part from Owin startup class:

```
`app.CreatePerOwinContext(AppDbContext.Create);
 app.CreatePerOwinContext<AppUserManager>(AppUserManager.Create);
```

to use OrmLite. How should I do this?

Just create a method that returns an OrmLiteFactory? Altough OrmLiteFactory does not implement IDisposable and will not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `OrmLiteConnectionFactory` should be registered as a singleton. You can then use it to create ADO.NET `IDbConnection` with:

```
using (var db = dbFactory.OpenDbConnection())
{
    //
}
```

Once it's registered as a Singleton you could use a lazy property pattern that's like in the `RepositoryBase` class to simplify data access, e.g:

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase : IDisposable, IRepository
{
    public virtual IDbConnectionFactory DbFactory { get; set; }

    IDbConnection db;
    public virtual IDbConnection Db
    {
        get { return db ?? (db = DbFactory.OpenDbConnection()); }
    }

    public virtual void Dispose()
    {
        if (db != null)
            db.Dispose();
    }
}
```

This will let access the `Db` connection like a normal connection and since it's `IDisposable` should dispose it after the request is executed, e.g:

```
public class MyController : RepositoryBase
{
    public List<Poco> GetPocos()
    {
        return Db.Select<Poco>();
    }
}
```